# Angular 9 - *ngFor over select drop down rendering options as blanks

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ngfor

Here is the scenario: I am trying to create a dropdown using *ngFor using an array of objects as a source.

I can console.log the array and everything is there, but options are being rendered as blank values. Regular  without *ngFor works fine.

That's how it's rendered: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu6RX.png

It's pretty much like this stuff I did to isolate the problem (it works here, **Just an example, Not the actual code**): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-example-ngfor-wcp3kt

Model for the options

```
export class BaseParametro {
  private _id: number;
  private _descricao: string;

  constructor(id: number, descricao: string) {
    this._id = id;
    this._descricao = descricao;
  }
  get id(): number {
    return this._id;
  }

  set id(id: number) {
    this._id = id;
  }
  get descricao(): string {
    return this._descricao;
  }

  set descricao(descricao: string) {
    this._descricao = descricao;
  }
}
```

Ts component:

```
export class CadastroComponent implements OnInit {
  tiposGeneros: BaseParametro[] = [];

  constructor() {
    this.tiposGeneros.push(new BaseParametro(1, "F"));
    this.tiposGeneros.push(new BaseParametro(2, "M"));
    this.tiposGeneros.push(new BaseParametro(3, "S"));
  }
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Quote: If I push new stuff to the tiposGeneros array, a new blank  appears on the UI

html code:

````
<div class="col-md-2">
   <label>Sexo</label>
   <div class="select-wrap">
      <select name="select">
         <option selected value="Selecione">Selecione</option>
         <option *ngFor="let sexo of tiposGeneros" [value]="sexo">{{sexo.descricao}}</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem wasn't int that part of code. Don't know much (yet) about components lifecycle, but due to an error in the father or caller component, the rendering wasn't working properly.

Corrected (hopefully) all the bugs and got the wanted result.